# Set new color for material-ui theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I am trying to set a new palette theme for my react app using material-ui's `createMuiTheme`. This is my code for my custom theme:

```
import {createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#1977d2', //blue
      contrastText: 'white',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#FF6600', //orange
      contrastText: 'white',
    },
    regular: {
      main: '#73C2FB' //maya
    }
  }
})

export default customTheme;
```

This is the code where I set the custom theme as the app's theme:

```
import './App.css';
import {ThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import customTheme from './themes/customTheme';
import App from './app/App';

function Main() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

And this is the code where I try to use color `regular` in a component:

```
BarButton = ({label, callBack}) => {
    return (
      <Button variant="contained" color="regular" className={this.props.classes.appBarButton} onClick={callBack}>{label}</Button>
    )
  }
```

When I use `color="primary"` or `color="secondary"`, it works, but `color="regular"` returns a default light gray color, instead of `#73C2FB`, that is a light blue.

I followed [these directions](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors) to achieve what I am aiming, but it is not working.

Comment: `Button` only [supports](https://material-ui.com/api/button/) `primary` and `secondary` theme colors. Various MUI components support different `palette` properties as string values for the `color` prop, but never custom ones. You need to apply this as `theme.palette.regular.main` via the `style` or `className` prop.

Comment: @hotpink thanks man, it worked. You should post it as an answer so everybody else with the same doubt get it solved. And you collect some points also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom theme properties can never be applied to any MUI component via the `color` prop. The reason for this is that MUI takes the the [interpolated string value](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L300) to apply styling via its default `props`. Your example of

```js
<Button variant="contained" color="regular">{label}</Button>
```

would look for a `containedRegular` property of `classes` that does not exist. IIUC MUI should also provide a [props validation error](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L354).

Instead, custom theme colors can be applied via the `styles` or `className` props.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  regular: {
    color: theme.palette.regular.main
  }
}))

const classes = useStyles()
const theme = useTheme()

<Button style={{color: theme.palette.regular.main}}>foo</Button>
<Button className={classes.regular}>bar</Button>
```